# Datepicker doesn't start to current month

Tags: jquery

I copied a javascript file from a page on the web , it uses a datepicker. What I noticed is that the month doesn't start to current month. Here is its code :

```
$( ".datepicker" ).datepicker({ 
        defaultDate: +7,
        showOtherMonths:true,
        autoSize: true,
        appendText: '(dd-mm-yyyy)',
        dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy'
    });
```

So how to make it start to current month ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe because you add 7 days? which makes it next month?

Answer (score 1):

remove this line or reduce no. of days

```
defaultDate: +7,
```

because it's adding 7 days in current date that's why it is showing next month